# What is the difference between One-way MEP and Request-response MEP?

Tags: jboss, soa, eai, jboss-esb

In the [JBossESB Programmer’s manual](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossesb/docs/4.10/manuals/html/Programmers_Guide/#sect-SOA_ESB_Programmers_Guide-Services_and_Messages-The_Message) it is mentioned as:

> “All interactions between clients and services within JBossESB occur through the exchange of Messages. In order to encourage loose coupling we recommend a message-exchange pattern based on one-way messages, i.e., requests and responses are independent messages, correlated where necessary by the infrastructure or application.”

But if requests and responses are independent messages for one-way MEP, then what is its difference between Request-response MEP?

And what is the actual advantage of using each of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Request-response

- AKA synchronous interaction, call-return.
- A sends a request to B and waits.
- B will process the request and send the response.
- A gets the response and moves on.

### One-way

- AKA asynchronous interaction, fire-and-forget.
- A sends a request/message to B, but does not wait for a response. It moves on to do other things.
- B will process the request/message and will be done.

### Sync-over-async

- The paragraph you quoted is alluding to this pattern...
- *If A-to-B uses one-way, what should we do if the results of processing the request/message need to be communicated back to A?*
- One option is to use the **sync-over-async** pattern:
- A sends a one-way request/message to B. This message typically contains a *correlation identifier*. A moves on to do other things.
- B will process the request/message.
- When the processing is done, B (or some other component that was called in the processing) will send an independent **one-way** message back to A with the results of processing.
- This second message can come milisseconds, minutes, hours after the original A-to-B request/message was sent. But it contains the same correlation identifier.
- This second message goes back to A or some other callback endpoint or queue that was pre-configured or indicated in the original message.
- Hohpe and Woolf call this pattern "request-reply". But I think this name is somewhat confusing (too close to "request-response").